# Implications Divergence of one subseries and convergence of one subseries on convergence or divergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

If $\sum a_n$ is infinite series such that $\sum\limits_{a_n \geq0} a_n$ is diverging to $+\infty$ and $\sum\limits_{a_n \leq0} a_n$ convergent, can we say $\sum a_n$ and any other rearrangement of this series will diverge to $+\infty$

Comment: The series is definitely not absolutely convergent, and is at best conditionally convergent. If it is conditionally convergent, then it can be rearranged to converge to any given value (or diverge).

Comment: it can't be conditionally convergent because for conditionally convergent series sum of series considering only negative terms will diverge to negative infinity @MPW